# header with a background image and an horizontal bar in the middle

Tags: css, html, header, nav

Currently, I'm learning html5 and css mostly by myself and I need to build a header with a background image and an horizontal bar in the middle where the logo and the navigation buttons are supposed to be. I tried in any way, but couldn't come up with a concrete solution. please, can anybody help?

Comment: can you share what you have tried, so we can help to fix that. There are many templates out there to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```css
.header{
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(http://i.ytimg.com/vi/bl1zq8EFQDQ/maxresdefault.jpg);
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <h1 class="header-title">Title</h1>
    <img class="header-logo" src="http://www.placehold.it/350x150">
    <div class="header-menu">
      <a href="http://www.google.es">Google</a>
      <a href="http://www.google.es">Google</a>
      <a href="http://www.google.es">Google</a>
      <a href="http://www.google.es">Google</a>
    </div>

  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but I'm rather looking for an horizontal bar cutting the image in the middle. I've tried this: